# Polynomial equation: find least degree polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I am searching for polynomials $P (x)$ and $Q (x)$ with integer coefficients at lowest terms and whose degrees are the lowest possible for which

(i) $P (0) = 0$, $P (1) = 1$, $P(2) = 0$ and $P (3) = -1$

(ii) $Q (0) = 1$, $Q (1) = -1$, $Q (2) = -1$ and $Q (3) = 1$

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) Necessarily, $P$ is divisible by $x$ and by $x-2$. By polynomial division, $P(x)=x(x-2)f(x)$ where $f$ is also a polynomial with integer coefficients. Then $-1=P(3)=3\cdot(3-2)\cdot f(3)=3f(3)$, which is absurd.

(ii) Similarly, $Q(x)-1$ is divisible by $x$ and by $x-3$, so $Q(x)-1$ is a multiple of $x(x-3)$. This time we are lucky, as already $Q(x)=x(x-3)+1=x^2-3x+1$ works (and of course no smaller degree polynomial works).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I upvoted you. What about if I took off the condition of $P (x)$ being with integer coefficients? Then what would $P (x)$ be? You know, that was precisely the problem that I came across when I tried to resolve it.